# Rack Middleware: use and run constructs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack

I am reading [this](https://www.amberbit.com/blog/2011/07/13/introduction-to-rack-middleware/) article on Rack Middleware. It states the following:

> Rack is more than interface that can be used to talk to web server.
>   **It’s used to group and order modules**, which are usually Ruby classes,
>   and specify dependency between them. **Rack::Builder puts these modules
>   on top of each other, creating stack-like structure of final web
>   application**.

So basically, we can use ruby classes to stack middleware on top of each other. We simply need a reference to the next middleware - kind of reminds me of the decorator design pattern.

All we need to do is have a constructor that takes the next application (middleware in the stack) as a paraemter. Second, we need to define a call method, which takes the environment hash as a parameter and returns an array of status code, environment hash and response body.

This is the example provided:

```
# shrimp.rb
class Shrimp
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app       
  end                

  def call(env)      
    @app.call(env)   
  end                
end                  

# config.ru
require 'rack'
require 'rack/lobster'
require 'shrimp'      

use Shrimp            
run Rack::Lobster.new </pre>
```

According to the Rack documentation, The use method adds middleware to the stack, and the run method dispatches to an application. I'm a little confused by this syntax. use adds Shrimp to the middleware stack and run passes Lobster instance into the Shrimp constructor? I am still confused by the role of run here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article you have linked to mentions that `Rack` comes with a sample application `Lobster` so yes, for a start, that is an app.

The `Shrimp` class is just a Ruby class which is how a middleware should be written.

In the `config.ru` file, you require the modules, register the middleware, and then run the application.

> use adds Shrimp to the middleware stack and run passes Lobster
>   instance into the Shrimp constructor?

You are right when you say `use` adds `Shrimp` to the middleware stack but `run` does not necessarily pass a `Lobster` instance into the `Shrimp` constructor. `run` just executes the `Rack` application and passing the `app` instance is how `Rack` works internally. The real thing happens in the `use` part where you register the middleware.

For example:

```
# config.ru
require 'rack'
require 'rack/lobster'
require 'shrimp_1'     
require 'shrimp_2'     
require 'shrimp_3'      

use Shrimp_1      
use Shrimp_2      
use Shrimp_3            
run Rack::Lobster.new </pre>
```

All three `Shrimp` classes will be passed the `app(Lobster)` instance in that order and this will be handled by `Rack` itself.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this? Maybe it can be helpful. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_on_rack.html#configuring-middleware-stack